# MySQL Delete statement

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating a database, using MYSQL and have inserted data however when I try and delete a row I have no luck can somebody please help me understand why the row doesn't delete? I have provided the created table the insert statements and the delete statement I used keep in mind the table displays as if it is full.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `new_schema2`.`Employee` (
  `EID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Fname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Lname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `AddressID` INT NOT NULL,
  `PayLevel` Decimal NOT NULL,
  `Jobtitle` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DateofEmployment` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

#Inserts begin Here
INSERT INTO new_schema2.Employee 
       (EID, Fname, Lname, AddressID, PayLevel, Jobtitle, DateofEmployment) 
       VALUES 
   (    0,'Andrew','Wiggins','7', 10000.00,'Stock Boy','08/11/12' );

INSERT INTO new_schema2.Employee 
       (EID, Fname, Lname, AddressID, PayLevel, Jobtitle, DateofEmployment) 
       VALUES 
       (1,'Andrew','Wiggins','7', 10000.00,'Stock Boy','08/11/12' );

INSERT INTO new_schema2.Employee  
       (EID, Fname, Lname, AddressID, PayLevel, Jobtitle, DateofEmployment) 
       VALUES 
       ('2','Nick','Smith','8', 20000.00,'Cashier','08/10/09' );


 INSERT INTO new_schema2.Employee 
       (EID, Fname, Lname, AddressID, PayLevel, Jobtitle, DateofEmployment) 
       VALUES 
       ('3','Niko','Jackson','9',40000.00,'Manager','05/10/06' );

INSERT INTO new_schema2.Employee 
       (EID, Fname, Lname, AddressID, PayLevel, Jobtitle, DateofEmployment) 
       VALUES 
       ('4','Dante','Henderson','10', 20000.00,'Cashier','06/15/09' );

INSERT INTO new_schema2.Employee 
       (EID, Fname, Lname, AddressID, PayLevel, Jobtitle, DateofEmployment) 
       VALUES 
       ('5','Jessica','Smith','8',22000.00,'Performer','08/09/11' );

INSERT INTO new_schema2.Employee 
       (EID, Fname, Lname, AddressID, PayLevel, Jobtitle, DateofEmployment) 
       VALUES 
       ('6','Alex','Grossi','15',100000.00,'Owner','08/11/02' );

#Delete statements begin here
DELETE FROM new_schema2.employee
WHERE EID = 0 AND Fname='Andrew' AND Lname='Wiggins' AND AddressID='7' AND  DateofEmployment='11/12/08'  AND PayLevel='10000.00'AND  Jobtitle = 'Stock Boy';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its not deleting because its failing on date condition.

You have field as

```
`DateofEmployment` DATE NOT NULL
```

When you insert `08/11/12` in MySQL it will become as `2008-11-12`

So the delete command should be as

```
DELETE FROM Employee
WHERE EID = 0 
AND Fname='Andrew' 
AND Lname='Wiggins' 
AND AddressID='7' 
AND  DateofEmployment='2008-11-12'  
AND PayLevel='10000.00'
AND Jobtitle = 'Stock Boy';
```

Check with

```
SELECT DateofEmployment FROM Employee
```

And see how data is shown, you will get the answer by yourself.

Comment: Ah thank you that was it @Abhik chakraborty thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to specify all columns in your delete

Use just this

```
   DELETE FROM new_schema2.employee
   WHERE EID = 0
```